# Subtheme's newly created CSS files aren't working

Tags: theming, .info

I'm currently using Zen for my subtheme, and attempting to add CSS to my .info file, but all my effort is for naught. The .info file is in my subtheme's root, and is named as such - mytheme.info. When I add a css file I input the following code

```
 stylesheets[all][] = css/background.css
```

The css file is in the css folder of my subtheme's directory. The particularly annoying thing is if I input the same code into a pre-existing css file it works perfectly fine, for example I input:

```
  /* HTML Background-Image */
html{
background-image: url(../../images/body-bg.jpg);
background-repeat: repeat;
background-position: center center;
```

Into components/misc.css and it loads up perfectly fine, background and all. 
I've read that using SASS might fix this problem, but I have a feeling that won't be the case

Am I doomed, never to create a new stylesheet and use it via the .info file, is anyone else experiencing this atrocity? Help Please :C

Comment: Importing via styles.css works, but is that the only alternative, why doesn't it work via .info file?

Comment: Just to make sure, you cleared your cache, right?

Comment: :) It clears on every page load, but just in case I cleared it manually as well, its more so css than js, I had some faulty js which I just fixed, though css is just ignored when I place it normally.

Comment: Are the permissions on the file something that a user can read?

Comment: Yeah I'd like to say that I learn from past mistakes :) But heres the thing after refreshing the page after around 10mins without interaction the page loads the background, can it be lag, because I cleared the cache before auto and manually, and I've checked the permissions, as well as constantly checking the css files, the .info file were all saved...

Comment: that's really weird, it doesn't make any sense, sorry for wasting your time it seems the site needed time before it began to recognize the background image, despite clearing the cache and reloading the page.

Comment: Clearing the cache *Should* cause the new css file to be read, but if there's some sort of server cache running on your server, that might be causing it.

Comment: That might of been the case indeed, well glad thats solved thanks again for helping me out XD